# What is the Big O of this modified Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: graph, runtime, dijkstra

I modified Dijsktra's Algorithm, which finds the shortest path between two nodes (s and v), to instead finds the last EDGE on a shortest path from node s to v, which are marked as X.

Now, if I'm given all the nodes that are marked X, I'm supposed to use the X nodes to basically retrace my steps backwards to find the shortest path between s and v.

My question is: What is the Big O of this modified algorithm?

Comment: If all algorithms were described like this, our world would descend into chaos.

Comment: What do you 'think' is the Big O? We can guide if you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you could do bookmarking while running dijkstra to help with the backtracking. You only need to create a predecessor for each node in the shortest path. and modify and add predecessors should be C*(number of nodes), which is linear to the input.